# Angular template form : disable submit if form didn't change

Tags: angular, forms, templates, disable

Here's my code

```
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
            <input placeholder="Order ID" type="text" id="orderId" class="form-control" 
            name="orderId" [(ngModel)]="orderId" required>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!(f.valid && f.dirty)">Search</button>
          </form>
```

I was expecting for the button to be disabled if input did not change but it did not. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dirty / ! pristine means the user has made a modification

In your case if you enter something and then revert it to it's original value Form will still remain **dirty**

To check if there are any difference you need to implement your own method.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-taxgae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What I want to do is prevent multiples submit if input remains the same. I cannot use dirty field?

Comment: @PaulSerre added a simple demo, the dirty flag remains true once you type something in text field and then revert it to it's original

Comment: @robert, you can mark the form as pristine when submit

Comment: @Eliseo you are right, my updated demo has a tiny method to compare original form values with current form values. Kind of "isThereAnyRealChange".

Answer (score 0):

As Robert say you can "play" with pristine. e.g.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="control">
  <button (click)="submit(form)" 
          [disabled]="!form.valid || form.pristine">submit</button>
</form>

  submit(form)
  {
    if (form.valid) //if valid mark as "pristine"
    {
      form.markAsPristine();
      console.log("submited") //do something
    }
    else
      form.markAllAsTouched(); //mark all the controls as touched
                               //to show the errors
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3wefma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)